# How to save and delete array value in usermeta?

Tags: wordpress

I need to save array value in usermeta. If user can update and delete any value. So i need add update and delete also. Is it possible in usermeta table or i need to create my custom table?

Comment: Yes it's possible but you need to maintain it on your external table.

Comment: insert and update array value in `user_meta` table, it will save as serialize data.

Comment: How we can do this. can you please add any example?